# Killing tor causes all the present and future windows to loose the frames

Tags: window, tor, kill

Almost, every time if `sudo pkill -f tor` which runs as root on startup. I loose all the frames(frameless) of my current and future windows. And I have noticed the Ubuntu tends to behave strangely(can't define it exactly) to such an extent that restart(didn't try log-off and log-in) seems to be a be better option for me. I don't think `tor` is the cause of this but I am speaking as per observation.

What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably killing processes you didn't intend to. The `-f` options matches on the full command line:

```
The pattern is normally only matched against the  process  name.
When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

To see which processes you're actually killing, do:

```
ps wwuxa |grep [t]or
```

The actual match as done by `pkill` is the same as done by `pgrep`. Compare the PIDs returned by `pgrep tor` vs. `pgrep -f tor`.

you'll see many processes; since you run `pkill` with `sudo`, this means you kill all those processes. My guess is `gtk-window-decorator` is the one whose absence causes the frames problem you describe. The rest of the strange behavior is due to the other system processes that also died.

In this case, since "tor" matches several system processes, you should specify a more strict regular expression, and not use `-f`. This may work:

```
pgrep  ^tor$
```

Don't use -f and ensure that it matches only one process, and that the process is indeed tor. Once you're satisfied, you can `pkill` instead of `pgrep`.

Finally, I'm unfamiliar with tor, but perhaps somewhere in the documentation you can find a more correct way to shut it down.

Answer (score 2):

Your `pkill` call kills all processes which have the string `tor` in their command line (such as `monitor` or `navigator` or `calculator` etc). Thus, I guess you're also killing important processes and end up in an unstable system.

I recommend stopping tor using:

```
sudo service tor stop
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tor stop
```